# Swift 3 scheduled timer capabilities

Tags: ios, swift, timer

I have a simple ios application that is handling a few asynchronous calls as well as a few scheduled timers to check on various things. I was wondering how the app performance will react if the timer is sped up or slowed down. If I just use the basic code below, will I see any difference between a 0.2 timer or a 5.0 timer?

```
func startTimer () {
    if timerTest == nil {
         timerTest =  Timer.scheduledTimer(
        timeInterval: TimeInterval(0.2),
        target      : self,
        selector    : #selector(ViewController.timerActionTest),
        userInfo    : nil,
        repeats     : true)
    }
}
```

Comment: will I see any difference between a 0.2 timer or a 5.0 timer - it really depends on what you're doing in timerActionTest

Comment: Why don't you try it yourself?

Comment: Im sure timer with short interval takes more CPU resources, isn't that not true in common sense?

Comment: I had tried a few different options but I was just seeing if anyone had experience with this as I couldn't find a definitive answer anywhere.